# vernam cipher outputs in hexadecimal numbers

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am using the same Vernam Cipher algorithm both on the server side and front to encrypt/decrypt passwords. however I do get the correct value when I decrypt the encrypted password, the encrypted password is not in ASCII (8 bit) characters. I want to encrypt the password only into 8-bit ASCII and then want to send to/from the server but since the output is only a bunch of hexadecimal numbers which i assume are not ASCII, it's becoming difficult for me to send it over the network and save in a database. any help would be appreciated.

```
const crypto = {

    key: 'catchmeifyoucan', 

    hash: function(string, key) {
        const len = string.length
        let ASCII = undefined; 
        let vernomChar = undefined;    
        let output = '';

        if(this.key.length < string.length) {
            this.key += this.key
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            ASCII = (string.charCodeAt(i) ^ key.charCodeAt(i))
            vernomChar = String.fromCharCode(ASCII)
            output += vernomChar
        }
        return output
    },

    encrypt: function(string) {
        return this.hash(string, this.key)
    },

    decrypt: function(string) {
        return this.hash(string, this.key)
    }
}

let encrypted = crypto.encrypt('text')
let decrypted = crypto.decrypt(encrypted)


console.log('encrypted',encrypted) // output: <0x17><0X04><0x0c><0x17>
console.log('decrypted',decrypted) // output: text
```

Comment: The typical method of transmitting binary data as ASCII is [base64 encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: In JavaScript, strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. (UTF-16 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set.) XOR-ing one with another could possibly create invalid code units or sequences. It definitely would work if both strings are from the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block plus the C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement block—but you should check your inputs.

Comment: so what possible way is there to get over this problem.i.e. i get answer in 128bit keycodes